# How to retain values of a select all checkbox when refreshed?

Tags: jquery, jsp, cookies, checkbox

The code is working fine when checking/unchecking each checkboxes but if I use to select all checkboxes and refreshes the page it returns to its default value which is unchecked.

Here is the script:

```
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){      
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $('input.box').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });    

        $("input.box").each(function() {
          var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
          if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
          $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
            }
            });

        $("input.box").change(function() {
            $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
            });
       });
});
    </script>
```

and Here is the HTML:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%" height="60%">
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All
            <td><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="1" /></td>
            <td><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="2" /></td>
            <td><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="3" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the jQuery.cookie plugin, so here's a solution that will work with that.

All it does is to save the state of the checkboxes to a cookie, then reads them back from the cookie on page reload.

Also, you probably shouldn't be using tables for layout purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="checkAll">Check all</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $("#checkAll").on("change", function() {
        $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
      });

      $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
        var checkboxValues = {};
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
          checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
      });

      function repopulateCheckboxes(){
        var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
        if(checkboxValues){
          Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
          });
        }
      }

      $.cookie.json = true;
      repopulateCheckboxes();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it seems not to work. When I try checking a checkbox and refresh the page it returns to being uncheck.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code verbatim, or did you alter it at all?
Also, this will not work locally in some browsers. Try it on a server.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code. I am using glassfish as a server.

Comment: Not sure about glassfish, but here's [a demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/cookie-checkbox.html) of it working.

Comment: I made it work. My question is that why does the scripts should be at the end of the body to work and why it wont work in the head area?

Comment: It's best practice to add scripts just before the closing </body> tag as then rendering begins sooner. If you want to put them in the <head> then you'll need to wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }`. 
If this has helped you, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes are all cleared up because when you refresh the page, the page is loaded again.

To retain the values that you checked, you have several options:

- Use cookies. It could get messy though to do it with that.
- Bind the check boxes to an event and via Ajax, send the values to the Server to save it over there. Now, when the page is reloaded, you could fetch the current values from the Server and set them.
- You could also opt for using HTML5 Local Storage. So, bind the checkboxes to your function and when the value is changed, save the same locally in Local Storage. This way there is no round trip to the server (especially if this is not too critical). Now when the page is reloaded again, you can check the current values in the Local Storage and set them.